# Display all features of layer using GetFeatureInfo in leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, getfeatureinfo

I wan't to display all the features of the WMS layer using GetFeatureInfo in leaflet.The features like point,state name or label and when I click on point I wan't to open new HTML page and display features without popup from Geo-Server.
I have done this code but output showing blank map window.Thanks

```
<html>
<head><title>India</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" />
<ul>
  <li><a href="#Anews">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">Urban Expansion</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Cities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Data</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Historical Data</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"></li>
</ul>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
      ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
    color:Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color:   #DCDCDC;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}     
</style>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="width: 2000px; height: 800px"></div>
<script>
var map = L.map('map', 
{
center: [20.5937,78.9629],
zoom:5
});
var usgs = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapper/wms", {
    layers:'mapper:ind_adm1',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: "USGS"

}).addTo(map);

function identify (e) {

var BBOX = map.getBounds().toBBoxString();
var WIDTH = map.getSize().x;
var HEIGHT = map.getSize().y;
var X = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
var Y = map.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mapper/wms';  

$.ajax({
    url:url,
    datatype: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success:handleJson
    }); 
    function handleJson(data) {
    var txt="";
for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
    var feature = data.features[i];
    console.log(feature);
    txt = txt.concat( L.Util.template("<h2>{appcode}</h2><p>{url}</p>", feature.properties));     
 }
   .setLatLng(e.latlng)
   .setContent(txt)
   .openOn(map);   
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your problem the blank map or the getfeatureinfo request or displaying the result of the getfeatureinfo?

Comment: Displaying the result of the GetFeatureInfo from Geo-server.